# To remove additional newlines

Tags: unix, newline

I have additional newlines coming in my input file. Below is a sample of my file. Please help.

```
H|20140705|5.dat
D|40904515|10013660|2|Trading Inc|1
D|40904517|10013685|2|trillion@trillionsales.com
info@trillionsales.com|3
D|40904518|10013719|2|Yearnlink Limited|1
D|40904519|10013722|2|Pine Tree Limited|1
T|004|19655819|20140705
```

If you notice, there seems to be an extra newline in field with value `tssson@tsas.com
info@trddd.com`.

I need this newline to be replaced with a space. Records should only begin with either - `H|` , `D|` or `T|`

I found the below command which removes a newline of any record that does not begin with a quote. However, I need the newline to be removed of any records that does not begin with `H|` , `D|` or `T|`  .

I am unable to modify the command below as it does not take the sequence of e.g. 'H|' (it only considers the first character).

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/ *\n\([^"]\)/ \1/; ta' -e 'P;D' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's just keep a buffer of lines to print:

```
$ awk '/^[HDT]/ {if (buff) print buff; buff=$0; next} {buff=buff""FS""$0} END{print buff}' file
H|20140705|5.dat
D|40904515|10013660|2|Trading Inc|1
D|40904517|10013685|2|trillion@trillionsales.com info@trillionsales.com|3
D|40904518|10013719|2|Yearnlink Limited|1
D|40904519|10013722|2|Pine Tree Limited|1
T|004|19655819|20140705
```

#### Explanation

- `/^[HDT]/ {if (buff) print buff; buff=$0; next}` if line starts with either H, D or T, do `{}`.
- `if (buff) print buff; buff=$0; next` if the buffer contains data, print it. Then, store current line in the buffer and use `next` to go to the next line.
- `{buff=buff""FS""$0}` in case the line does not start with H/D/T, append its content to the buffer.
- `END{print buff}` print the buffer after processing the file. This is done to print the last stored buffer, that is, everything from the last line starting with H/D/T (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed ':a; N; /\n[HDT]/!s/\n//g; t a;' yourfile
```

Here,

- `N` will read next line and append it to existing line with `\n` delimiter
- `/\n[HDT]/!` if next line doesn't start with `H` or `D` or `T`
- `s/\n//g` removes the new line.

**Test:**

```
$ sed ':a; N; /\n[HDT]/!s/\n//g; t a;' yourfile
H|20140705|5.dat
D|40904515|10013660|2|Trading Inc|1
D|40904517|10013685|2|trillion@trillionsales.cominfo@trillionsales.com|3
D|40904518|10013719|2|Yearnlink Limited|1
D|40904519|10013722|2|Pine Tree Limited|1
T|004|19655819|20140705
```